# SQL Conditional Inner Join Where

Tags: mysql, inner-join, conditional-statements

I need to a conditional inner join with where.

I have an assessment form that has three particular fields: country, Degree and subject.

There is another form named "responds template" with the same fields: country, Degree and subject.

Advisers create some responds template by different condition to answer faster.

Advisers reply to the assessment inquiries in a reply form then I need to filter list of related responds as a drop down list base on user section in those filed.

for example if a user chose Country: USA, Degree: Master and subject: Math then I need to filter responds template based on these section and show only the responds templates for Country: USA, Degree: Master and subject: Math.

I used this code but it works just for the first condition "country" and doesn't work for second and third AND.

and also I need to filter by country and degree if there is not any item matched with first condition.

```
WHERE {thistable}.id IN (
    SELECT app_responds.id
    FROM app_responds AS app_responds
    INNER JOIN app_assessment AS app_assessment
        ON app_responds.destination = app_assessment.destination_country AND
           app_responds.degree = app_assessment.degree AND
           app_responds.field_of_study = app_assessment.field_of_study_id AND
           app_responds.subject = app_assessment.subject_id
)
```

Comment: The usage of "And" is correct based on your desired result. One thing that stands out to me is that you equate "field_of_study" in one table with the "field_of_study_id" in another table (same for 'subject'). Is that intentional or an oversight. We can't tell w/o you sharing the table structures.

Comment: Also, why use "AS" aliases if you don't change or shorten the name?

Comment: I need to return records based on equals values in two different tables. I didn't get your point exactly.

Comment: Fieldofstudy is likely a text field based on its name, fieldofstudyid is likely an autoincremented integer, based on its name. So then they should never be equal.

Comment: Understand, No both of them are integer. They are join from other tables and just save id's

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use OR instead of AND. That gives you any match from your conditions. If you use AND all tree conditions should be TRUE in order to get a value

Comment: Yes, I spent more than 5 hours on it but it didn't work. It just works for the first condition!!!